# Can anyone suggest a software for automated database system

Tags: web, raspberry-pi, database-connection

Can anyone help with my problem. Im trying to make system with collects data, stores it to a database and create a wep page that could show the data that ive gathered. The system is already done, database is okay. I want to migrate my system's data from the database to the web page ive created, automatically. i need your suggestion what software i could use to make it possible. Im using raspberry pi 3+B

Answer (score 0):

You can python, flask and mysql libraries to develop such system.